# How to migrate a TCP socket from one container to another in the same host

Tags: linux, docker, sockets

I have a docker container with a process (be it netcat) listening on a certain port, with the other end of the connection being a netcat client in a Ubuntu host. At some point, another container is created (in the same host) and I want to migrate this TCP connection/socket from the first container to this new one. Is this possible, and how could I achieve this?

The newly created container is configured with the same IP and MAC as the first one. However, after deleting the original container, the connection is lost as the original socket is deleted, and for some reason the nc client cannot reconnect. Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: How would you do this task without Docker?  (I don't think this is possible in Unix in general; terminating a process will always close all of its network listeners.)

Comment: In my use case, Docker containers must be used. But if we take them away, then I believe an analogy would be using a netns, then creating a new netns and moving the tcp socket from the original netns to the new one. Then, deleting the original netns.